# Как в обьекте шаблона вызвать сначала конструктор по умолчанию а потом конструктор с параметром?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Здравствуйте интересует такой вопрос. Например если в обычном классе (допустим класс Dog) есть обьект dog и для того чтобы в этого обьекта вызвать конструктор несколько раз можно сделать так :

```
Dog dog= new Dog();
```

Вопрос а можно ли сделать что-то в этом роде но для обьекта шаблона. Допустим у меня есть шаблонный класс Sum и его метод first. Сначала я вызываю конструктор по умолчанию
`Sum<int> first;`
а потом нужно для этого обьекта еще раз вызвать конструктор но уже с параметром. Как это можно сделать ?

Comment: Конструктор вызывается один раз - при создании объекта. Так что ваше желание "для объекта вызвать конструктор" выглядит, скажем прямо, странно. Как странно же выглядит запись `Dog dog= new Dog();` (С++ - не Java...) или упоминание о методе `first` в контексте "вызываю конструктор по умолчанию Sum<int> first;". Конечно, можно дать объекту и методу одинаковое имя, но что-то мне говорит, что тут вы несколько запутались...

Answer (score -1):

Можно делать то же самое с `new`, передавая любые параметры:

```
Sum<int>* first = new Sum<int>{};
```